# How to make it so on page load I can scroll the page, not the embedded PDF object

Tags: javascript, html

I embedded a PDF object on to my page.  Now when I load the page and scroll with the mouse wheel, it scrolls up and down inside the PDF, instead of the actual page.  I have to first click in some whitespace on the page, and then I can scroll.

Do I need to create some other object that I can set focus to on page load?

Answer (score 0):

Give the body of your page an id/name tag and set focus to that or if you're loading the pdf in an iframe just set focus to parent in the iframe

Comment: I've tried this by making a little function that does a document.getElementById('bodyID').focus(); then calling that function in the body onload.  The function calls, I tested that with an alert, but the problem persists.

Comment: There are many problems with the inline PDF opener often down to specific browsers on specific platforms rather than generally.  See this page http://forums.asp.net/p/1013770/1360146.aspx  there's a long indepth discussion as well as alot of code that "works" the basis is for asp.net/c# BUT the javascript can be brought across no problems as is its not php related